# Reopen "How can I balance adventures around one of the party members being a monarch?"

Tags: support, specific-question, vote-to-reopen

The question: [How can I balance adventures around one of the party members being a monarch?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/109671/how-can-i-balance-adventures-around-one-of-the-party-members-being-a-monarch)

On RPG stack exchange the question was held for being too broad, but I edited it so it would be asking a more concrete question. It was edited within a day or so of the hold, but I think nobody got around to it in time, as it was closed.

I'd like to have it reopened if the edit is considered acceptable.

Comment: Note: just 4 sentences got changed since the closing.

Answer (score 5):

Reopening needs 5<sup>*</sup> votes to reopen, and currently it is in the queue. At the time of this writing, 4 people believe the edits (4 lines) do warrent a reopening.

You did add/change about 4 or 5 sentences since it as closed. They illustrate the problem, but do they cut down the broadness? That is the question each of the users that has enough points has to ask themselves when answering that vote.

I can't state my opinion on this question without possibly influencing the vote, so I abstein from stating it.

*<sub>Five reopen votes by users with [reopen voting privileges](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions), or one reopen vote by a moderator.</sub>

Comment: Why not state your opinion? There's absolutely nothing wrong with doing so

Comment: @Wibbs Because I try not to influence the balance here, or state my opinion on this question. I tried to shed light on the process here, and as a side note: we only got 9 questions in the [tag:vote-to-reopen], and this is pretty much one of 3 that asks to reopen a specific question. The others are about the reopening system: "I accidentally Voted, is that bad?", "Mods and Reopening", "Tug of open/close-War?", "does voting out of the queue count?", "How to reopen if you lack Rep" and one that is arguably more VtC related

Comment: What is too broad about the question? I'm willing to negotiate since the way the question was originally worded made a few posters think it was a question about mass combat, so it may just be a miscommunication on my part.  Also, several edits have occured since you posted your answer (mine and others), see if that helps.